# How to fix javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, struts, tomcat8

My app is on a digital ocean server with ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-43-generic x86_64)

when I run java -version i get this output:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I'm using struts 2 and i've installed tomcat 8.0.18 to deploy it.

Almost everything is fine with my app, except that when I click on a button that saves some specific information from a form i got this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Also the root cause is this (just as the same error show at the bottom)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Index Value
org.apache.commons.beanutils.expression.DefaultResolver.getIndex(DefaultResolver.java:94)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:917)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:467)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PopulateActionForm.populate(PopulateActionForm.java:50)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPopulateActionForm.execute(AbstractPopulateActionForm.java:60)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**weird thing**

When i deploy the same app on a windows machine it runs perfectly fine, everything works! When I use a unix (ubuntu 14.04, ubuntu 14.10, fedora 21) it just doesn't work and i got the error above.

¿How can i fix it? 
Many thanks!

Sorry if this is a noob bug, i'm new on struts development

Comment: Is there any dropdown in your jsp ?

Comment: Can you dump out all the request parameters? Do they match up with the ActionForm bean? Especially take care of collection types.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-334.

Comment: @looser yes, but as i told when i deploy the same app (it is actually a .war file) on another server it runs perfectly.

Comment: @Thilo they do... I've reviewed the code three times in a row and nothing seems to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

In my case select tag has attribute mutiple will cause this issue.